# Android Orientation Change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

My tabbed app does not redisplay the view with an orientation change.

I added

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to the main tab activity and to each activity in the manifest.

I added to each activity this method:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.active_alt);
    mColorLegendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colorbtn);
    mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celltitle1);
    TextView mStatusView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celltitle2);
    mStatusView1.setText(mStatusView1.getText()+"testcase1");
    mStatusView.setText(mStatusView.getText()+"testcase");
    initUI();
}

public void initUI() {
    l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    EfficientAdapter efficientAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(mContext);
    l1.setAdapter(null);
    l1.setAdapter(efficientAdapter);
}
```

On launch, the tabs, list, button and textview are displayed correctly.
When I change the orientation in the emulator, only the tabs are displayed none of the other widgets, the screen is black.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've experienced a very similar problem, and have found a different workaround. It has manifested in a couple of different instances. See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103639/android-orientation-change-causes-imageview-to-dissapear).

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly this problem. After much trial and error, I eventually solved it by making a one-line change to the manifest.

The trick is to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to your `TabActivity`'s entry in the manifest. Leave all the child activities alone. Don't even bother implementing `onConfigurationChanged()`, not even in the `TabActivity`.

I don't know how or why this seems to work, but the effect is the layout is refreshed, and both the tabs and the child activity content are redrawn correctly in the new orientation.

Comment: Then it will not take xml from layout-land folder if we write in maifest above line code.

Answer (score 1):

With success I found that the best way to have screen changes with most control is to make your layout xml for landscape mode in a seperate xml like so:

```
res/layout-land/youractivity.xml
```

using  /layout/  and /layout-land/   for your layouts as well as Graham Borland answer is golden.

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
                  android:launchMode="standard"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  >
```

the above snippet is what made mine work.  :)

ohh I do believe the "unspecified" is what allows the system to do what it thinks is best...

Good luck!

Comment: Are there any other things to add? I added the res/layout-land/main.xml but it didn't refresh the view when on landscape mode. The view being displayed is still the layout for portrait.

Comment: try adding:

android:screenOrientation="unspecified"

Give that extra property a shot and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In `Mono` for `Android` with a target API greater then `13` I found that the line which would go inside the namespace but outside the `Activity class`:

```
[Activity (Label = "Viewer",  ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation|ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

lead to the triggering of `OnConfigurationChanged()` even though changing the manifest had not.

Answer (score 0):

Could it just be that your layout doesn't work in the landscape/portrait mode? Try starting you app after rotating, check if that gives the same results. If so: fix your layout :D

Comment: The app works in both orientations. It does not redisplay when orientation changes in either direction.

Comment: Tabs...are you using a tabactivity with tabs that are activities on their own? Did you add code to your tabactivity as well? I'd add some logging to check what onconfigchanged functions are called, and when.

Comment: Yes, I did add the onconfigchanged to the tabactivity, and with logs I can see that onconfigchanged is called in both the tab activity and the activity being displayed. The issue is that the view is not shown.

Comment: sorry, out of ideas then. maybe someone can see something if you add more of the code? this looks fine to me, but don't know what happens to your tabHost and all