# Android orientation change

Tags: android

I am using this code to detect layout orientation changes but the following code uses the same portrait layout instead of layout kept in layout-land.

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

```
  <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Orientation Change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616176/android-orientation-change)

Comment: What do you mean? When you change the orientation, is it falling always in "else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){" case and displaying "portrait"? Or layout is not getting changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override **onConfigurationChanged** method then **onCreate** method does not called while Screen Orientation changed. Your activity is not restarted. That's why you are getting same layout.

You need to call **setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)** in **onConfigurationChanged** method.